# Solr searching by operator OR

Tags: .net, solr, solr-query-syntax

I'm using Apache Solr and I try to find one item by this query:

```
server_url?debug=true
&defType=edismax
&fq=custom_type:custom
&indent=true
&limit=10
&page=0
&q=custom_words:contact
&wt=json
```

Where custom_words - It's a type in schema, where I need to search.
It looks like this:

```
    {
    "id": "1",
    "url": "12",
    "custom_type": [
      "custom"
    ],
    "custom_name": "Contact Us",
    "custom_words": [
      "contact us",
      "Contact Us"
    ],
    "language": "en",
  },
```

How can I change query, if I want to receive this item for the following queries: "contact", "us contact".
I mean, that the order of the entered words and their number would not be important, that would not have to write down all possible combinations in the custom_words
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Make the custom words field be a textfield with a StandardTokenizer or WhitespaceTokenizer, together with a lowercasefilter. That will break `contact us` into two separate tokens, `contact` and `us`. When searching for `contact`, Lucene will match against the `contact` token and give you the document back.